# Error 500 Internal Server Error while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request

Tags: php, webserver, hosting, symfony-3.4

I created a project that works on the local server.

When I upload it, the server displays this error.

[image]

The PHP version in local server

[image]

The PHP version in web server linux

[image]